# Cannot prevent UITableView from moving when bounds change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, frame, bounds

I have an `UITableView` created using this method (inside a `UIViewController`):

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews {
if (!self.tableView) {
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 120, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-120) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.superview.autoresizingMask= NO;
//        [self.tableView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    [self.tableView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.tableView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}
```

}

When the application enters the background and the view controller is then reloaded, the `tableView` moves lower as a result (I think) of the bounds changing. However, I have tried turning auto layout off in storyboard, turning the `autoresizesSubviews` "BOOL" of `self.view` and of `self.tableView` and have even tried changing the constraints on the `tableView`. Every time the view loads, the content moves. Furthermore, I've put the initiation into `viewDidLoad`, but then the actual sizes don't map to the screen. How do I force the `tableView` to stay fixed after initiating it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: Tip: You should not initialize your views in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Initialize your tableView in `viewDidLoad`, and then set the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: So that the frame updates when the bounds change? Or will it still suffer from being moved?

Comment: That's right, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called every time the bounds change, so setting the frame in that method will ensure that you tableView is always sized according to the current bounds.

Comment: @michaels. Thanks for that, do you want to make a token answer and I'll mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called only once in the view controller lifecycle, and is called before the view has it's bounds property set. This is the perfect place to initialize your subviews.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 120, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-120) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.superview.autoresizingMask= NO;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    [self.tableView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.tableView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}
```

`viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called every time the bounds change, so setting the frame in that method will ensure that your tableView is always sized according to the current bounds:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 120, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-120);
}
```